# How to get result based on specific keywords using Google App Engine NO-SQL datastore query in java?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We use GoogleInfo table, in that table, we store scopes of application.   e.g."https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
and I am trying to get a result based on some keyword like "drive" from scopes, based on that keyword I am trying to get a result. following is my code. Please suggest.

```
String keywords[] = {"admin","drive","gmail","userinfo"};

Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT scopes FROM com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.dataaccesslayer.insights.google.drive.GoogleInfo where :p.contains(scopes)");

result =  (List) query.execute(Arrays.asList(keywords));
List tempResult = new ArrayList();
tempResult.addAll(result);
return tempResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using JDO [1] and the PersistanceManager [2].

As far as I can see the query you are trying to execute might be wrong. Check how to perform queries with JDO [3].

Your query is:

```
String keywords[] = {"admin","drive","gmail","userinfo"};
Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT scopes FROM com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.dataaccesslayer.insights.google.drive.GoogleInfo where :p.contains(scopes)"); 
result = (List) query.execute(Arrays.asList(keywords));
```

Looks like you want to do something like:

```
//Query for all persons with lastName equal to Smith or Jones
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class, ":p.contains(lastName)");
q.execute(Arrays.asList("Smith", "Jones"));
Person.class is the kind
Arrays.asList("Smith", "Jones")
```

This parameter ":p.contains(lastName)" that defines lastName is the property we want to check on.
You are setting the class as com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.dataaccesslayer.insights.google.drive.GoogleInfo, I suppose that this is the full Java name package where the class habits, and the class name is GoogleInfo. So you could try:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(GoogleInfo.class, ":p.contains(scopes)");
q.execute(Arrays.asList("admin","drive","gmail","userinfo"));
```

You want to retrieve scopes. I assume that you want to use the REST API. So inside :p.contains(“scopes”) might go another property related to your keyWords that is in the Entity you want to retrieve, maybe an array property?

Here I share with you some docs that might be useful [4][5].

Hope this helps!

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2

[2] http://massapi.com/method/javax/jdo/PersistenceManager.newQuery-4.html

[3] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/queries

[4] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview#comparison_with_traditional_databases

[5] https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference